# Repeatedly split data in training (0.75) and test (0.25) for cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, validation, partitioning, model-evaluation

What kind of cross validation is it called when we randomly split the data into 0.75 training and 0.25 test data set. And this split is done 1000 times.

Comment: Why would you want to do it 1000 times?

Comment: I did it a number of times to get the average accuracy. So is it wrong to validate this way?

Comment: Ohh okay.  I mis-read it.  I think it sounds like the `Holdout method`, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 6):

This is frequently referred to as **repeated training-test split**, or **leave-group-out cross-validation**, or **Monte Carlo cross-validation**$^1$. Note that this should be done with more splits than regular CV (which would have e.g. 10 partitions) - so you doing it 1000 times is a good idea.

*$^1$ See e.g. Applied Predictive Modeling by Kuhn and Johnson, Springer, 2013.*

Comment: what is the different between this and bootstrap?

Comment: @Matemattica Just looked it up to not give wrong answers: bootstrap by definition does sampling with replacement, which makes it - in this regard - different from most of the other approaches, which usually do sampling without replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Think you are referring to ShuffleSplit.

Shuffle Split perform random permutation of given data set and splits the data to train and test sets based on the chosen proportions you provide it as input.

As opposed to any other CV method - Shuffle Split never assumes that the folds it produce will be different than one another, meaning samples can appear in more than one fold.
This is really useful in cases like yours - where you may want a large number of random folds - but have a finite data set that can't be divided into a 1000 different folds, in strategies like KFold.

A link to sklearn's implementation of Shuffle Split:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen it under the name of repeated set validation. (The difference between hold-out and set validation in that context being that set validation results were used like cross validation results as surrogate for a final model trained on all data whereas hold out was refering to using the test results for exactly the model that was tested.